# What is a word that describes someone who acts virtuous to attract people but really isn't

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes someone who pretends to be virtuous in order to please or gain people's trust.

I'm looking for a word that precisely has this definition. I've thought of words like hypocrite, sanctimonious, and insincere but they don't encompass all the components in the definition I gave.

Thanks

Comment: Please indicate what words you've considered and rejected, and why.

Comment: Two-faced or pretentious?

Comment: I sometimes call people like that 'whited sepulchres' which, my wife says, ages me somewhat.

Comment: @Michael Harvey ages you because it's from the Bible? I don't get it. Or is there some other reference I'm missing? Did whited sepulchre use to be common in everyday language?

Comment: I am in my 60s. When I was a child at school, we were forced to study the Bible. This is much less common now, vanishingly so. The term would be familiar to many people of my background and age.

Comment: In my opinion "sanctimonious" is close to perfect for the description you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not strictly referring to pretending to be *virtuous*, ***poseur*** might work for you.

> ***[poseur](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/poseur)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> A person who behaves affectedly in order to impress others.

(From the Oxford Dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

*Hypocrite* is usually identified with publicly presenting a false front of virtue. *Phony*, *charlatan*, *fake*, and *four-flusher* also indicate falsity, but not necessarily in the area of virtue.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd definition of "virtue signaling" fits, but perhaps "fake virtue signaling" is more clear for your context? my own search for the same word led me here, but I'm not yet satisfied.... I'll keep looking.

Urban Dictionary lists six reader-supplied definitions of [*virtue signalling*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Virtue%20Signalling&amp=true&defid=8889507).